# Defining types in Haskell in terms of other types and typeclasses struggling

Tags: haskell, types

Can someone please explain to me how we can define a new type in terms of itself in Haskell. Below is the snippet of code I am struggling to understand. I do not understand how we can define a new type in terms of itself. We are saying `Card` is a new type with constructors `Card Rank Suit`. What does this even mean?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
data Suit = Spades | Hearts | Clubs | Diamonds
              deriving (Show, Eq)

data Rank = Numeric Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
              deriving Show

data Card = Card Rank Suit
              deriving Show
```

Answer (score 2):

> We are saying `Card` is a new type with constructors `Card Rank Suit`. What does this even mean?

Well, first of all it's *wrong*. `Card` is a new type with the single constructor `Card`; the latter takes two arguments, which are of type `Rank` and `Suit`.

The confusing thing here is that you're really dealing with two different things that are both called `Card`. Let's disambiguate:

```
data CardT = CardC Rank Suit
              deriving Show
```

That expresses the same definition, but now it's clear that the type and constructor aren't the same thing. `CardT` lives in the *type-level language*, `CardC` lives in the value-level language.

```
> :t CardC
CardC :: Rank -> Suit -> CardT
```

Comment: Extremely pedantic comment: since you're emphasizing the term and value levels, let's just name the type constructor `CardType` and the data constructor `CardValue`.

Comment: So, CardC is basically a function which takes a Rank and Suit as inputs and produces an output of type CardT?

Comment: @chepner hmyeahyou'rerightinprinciple. I didn't really want to get into the concept of _nullary_ constructors, though.

Comment: Also does that mean say if I had : data Hand = Empty | Add Card Hand then the Hand type has the data constructor Add Card Hand where Add takes two arguments Card and Hand and adds the Card argument to the Hand argument? Apologises if I am still making mistakes, this is all very new to me!

Comment: @harleengulati03 yes, it _is_ a function which takes a `Rank` and `Suit` as inputs and produces an output of type `CardT`. It's not _only_ that, though; a constructor is a function that can be _unwrapped_ again to reveal its original arguments (the “contained” values); mathematically speaking: an _injective_ function.

Comment: @harleengulati03 second comment also looks right. Note that in this cases both mentions of `Hand` are actually the same thing, both are the type.

Comment: cheers thanks so much!